# Android app - Lite version or paid version

Tags: android, android-version

I am developing one android app with single source library. I wish to submit the app for both free and paid version. For free version I planned to disable some functionalities and give more functionalities for paid one. Is there any way to find the android app is free or paid by java code?

EDIT 1:
In windows phone "**App.xaml.cs**" file contains the following method to identify the free or paid version of the Windows Phone app.

```
private void Application_Launching(object sender, LaunchingEventArgs e)
{
   var license = new Microsoft.Phone.Marketplace.LicenseInformation();
   IsTrial = license.IsTrial();
}
```

Here IsTrail is the property which returns true or false. Is there any method is available for Android to detect the Free or Paid version.?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Play Services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html) doesn't offer any API for accessing Google Play metadata in relation to the running app. [Application Licensing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html) might be a way forward, but user Sandy mentioned that it cannot be used in a paid app (sounds odd though).

I would suggest another way forward though:

- Unless you offer a single version of the app with an in-app purchase to upgrade from a free to a paid version you have to upload two different versions to Google Play (since the package name cannot be the same for two apps). There's no way around this fact.
- Since you have to build two different versions of the app you could at compile-time preprocess the compiled code and replace the parts of the code that will differ between a free and a paid version. With carefully designed code this should be no problem at all. [Library projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects) should be suitable for this.
- Another option would be to provide two different sets of data/config-files at compile time where you through the means of config/launch parameters control what parts of the code should be activated.

If you could provide a bit more information about the app it's easier to suggest a good solution. Is it a game where the paid app has more levels? Is it an app where some functionality isn't available in the free version? Is it an app that is limited to a certain number of uses a day in the free version?

UPDATE: You mention that you want to disable comments in the free app while in the paid app the comment should be posted to your server. I think the best way would be to separate the paid and free logic into two library projects and use one project when building the paid version and one when building the free version:

1. Create two [library projects](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects), one with the code for the free app and one for the paid app. In both projects you should have a class called CommentPoster or something like that. Have both classes implement an interface from your main project that defines the method that will be called when the user posts a comment, let's call it ICommentPoster and have a method called postComment(String comment).
2. Let the postComment() method of your CommentPoster class in the paid version send the comment to the server
3. Let the postComment() method of your CommentPoster class in the free version create a dialog, toast or some other means of telling the user that this function isn't available. You could optionally have another method called isAvailable() in ICommentPoster if you want to let the user know beforehand that comments aren't available

If you really don't like the idea of two library project and want to keep all code in a single project you could do some preprocessing and include one out of two different config files and have the app read the config file to check if comments should be available or not. This has the disadvantage of being hackable quite easily since you need to have all the code in your app and it's simply a matter of modifying the config file to get the benefits of a paid version (most probably a higher risk on rooted devices I guess)

Comment: For example, word to pdf converter, the save button is disabled for free version and enabled for the paid version or the free version displays a dialog "Paid version required" message.

Comment: I am creating the app which sends feedback and comments like app. For free version the comment is not posted and for paid it should be posted.

Comment: Updated with a suggestion to use library projects for code that differs between the two versions

Comment: Thanks for the reply Britzl. I have updated the question. Can you please give me the suggestion?

Comment: No, there is no out-of-the-box solution for offering a trial and paid version in the same APK as there is for a Windows Phone XAP. The closest would be the Google Play licensing service but that is primarily used to confirm that a paid app in fact has been paid for.

Comment: If I am using the licensing service, how can I get the app is paid one?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html "The Android SDK provides a downloadable set of library sources that you can include in your application project: the Google Market Licensing package. The License Verification Library (LVL) is a library you can add to your application that handles all of the licensing-related communication with the Google Play licensing service. With the LVL added to your application, your application can determine its licensing status for the current user by simply calling a method and implementing a callback that receives the status response."

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for this currently. You can check whether a user has bought a paid app using the licensing service (LVL), but it cannot be used in a paid app.